# How to fixed an array with values for a page untill another value is posted?

Tags: php, arrays

i have two page one.php and two.php
one.php for form submit and two.php for receiving the form values.

In two.php, i have an array to insert the posted value in it and redirect again to one.php. Is it possible to fixed that array with values until another post is coming from one.php?

If my question is not clear ,plz let me know...

Thanks....

Comment: Yo should post the code of the two pages, is not clear what you need to do :D

Comment: You could also post to the same script, that generates the form. This would save some logic and is less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

No. [HTTP is stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). Every new request will wipe out the old page and re-build the array. You should probably use [$SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) or some other storage for a data source that will persist across requests.

Comment: what user vissionary said is absolutely true, you can also cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using SESSION or any Caching techniques.
On each request store the POST values to SESSION or Cache and retrieve those data as needed.

```
$_SESSION('post_data') = $_POST;
```

You can append the current time stamp while storing to distinguish the POST values or store some distinct vales like( username etc..)